# No puedo obtener latitud y longitud después de encender GPS

Tags: ionic4

Mi aplicación **Ionic 4** muestra un mapa con rutas, desde la ubicación de mi móvil hasta cualquier ubicación, elegida antes.

Cuando el GPS está encendido al iniciar la aplicación (en app.component.ts), **recupera correctamente** la latitud y la longitud, y dibuja el mapa.

Cuando el GPS está apagado, la aplicación le pide al usuario que lo encienda (ver código adicional por favor).

Cuando el usuario enciende el GPS, no obtengo la latitud y la longitud con la función "getLocationCoordinates" (ver código por favor). Aparecen como **undefined**. ESTE es mi error, por lo que pido ayuda por favor.

Adjunto el código, muchas gracias!

```
getLocationCoordinates() {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 20000, timeout: 120000 }).then((resp) => {
      this.global.origin = { lat: resp.coords.latitude, lng: resp.coords.longitude };
      this.global.latitude = resp.coords.latitude;
      this.global.longitude = resp.coords.longitude;
      alert("Go!"); //never shown when user turns GPS on
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.presentAlertNoGPS();
});
```

código adicional, en app.component.ts:

```
checkGPSPermission() {
    this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION).then(
      result => {
        if (result.hasPermission) {
          //If having permission show 'Turn On GPS' dialogue
          this.askToTurnOnGPS();
        } else {
          //If not having permission ask for permission
          this.requestGPSPermission();
        }
      },
      err => {
        alert(err);
      }
    );
  }
  requestGPSPermission() {
    this.locationAccuracy.canRequest().then((canRequest: boolean) => {
      if (canRequest) {
      } else {
        //Show 'GPS Permission Request' dialogue
        this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
          .then(
            () => {
              // call method to turn on GPS
              this.askToTurnOnGPS();
            },
            error => {
              //Show alert if user click on 'No Thanks'
              this.presentAlertNoGPS();
            }
          );
      }
    });
  }
  askToTurnOnGPS() {
    this.locationAccuracy.request(this.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).then(
      () => {
        // When GPS Turned ON call method to get Accurate location coordinates
        this.getLocationCoordinates()
      },
      error => {
        this.presentAlertNoGPS();
      }
      alert('Error requesting location permissions ' + JSON.stringify(error))
    );
  }
```

Comment: No sé muy bien como funciona tu código, pero normalmente el GPS tarda un rato después de encenderse en encontrar su ubicación. ¿Estás pidiendo el dato inmediatamente?

Comment: Gracias por responder, si, lo pido inmediatamente ya que se utiliza para dibujar el mapa y la ruta

Comment: ¿Has probado a ir repitiendo la petición (por ejemplo, cada 5 segundos) hasta que te deje de aparecer como *undefined*? Puedes ponerle lógica para que si al cabo de uno o dos minutos de hacer peticiones salga del bucle (para evitar un bucle infinito). No he trabajado con GPS así que es solo una sugerencia, pero es lo único que se me ocurre.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, voy a investigar si a partir de tu idea puedo idear algo

Comment: No he podido lograrlo. Si el gps está on al inicio de la app, funciona de maravilla. Si lo enciendo a demanda, porque inicié con el gps off, tarda aproximadamente 2 minutos en encontrar lat y lng (mi conexión wifi es excelente). Es inaceptable. Gracias !